# Create multiple instances of class using guice

Tags: java, guice

There is a class that holds some state and implements an interface. This class should be registered multiple times at a GUICE module with different configurations. The class has dependencies to other beans, which should be injected by GUICE.
Example:

```
public class MenuItemImpl implements MenuItem {
  @Inject
  AnyService service;

  public MenuItemImpl(String caption) {
    this.caption = caption;
  }
 //...
}
```

Instead of using a c'tor parameter a public setter is possible, too.

In the Guice module I want to bind multiple instances of the MenuItemImpl class.

I tried to use a `Provider<T>`, however, dependent beans are not injected in this case.

```
Multibinder<MenuItem> binder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), MenuItem.class);
binder.addBinding().toProvider( new Provider<MenuItem>() {
  @Override
  public MenuItem get() {
      return new MenuItemImpl("StartCaption");
  }
}
```

I took a look at @Assist annotiation. However, I want to specify the configuration during binding phase in module and not when consuming the bean.

The only workaround I see is creating different subclasses for every configuration which is bad style imho and not what is OO is intended to be.

Comment: This is discussed as the *Robot Legs* problem in the Guice FAQ.  See *How do I build two similar but slightly different trees of objects?* in https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, this case is not about different object trees. It's more about configuring state of GUICE managed beans to avoid deep inhertance hierarchies.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class A
{
    @Inject
    @Named("startCaption")
    private MenuItem menuItem;

}

public class B
{
    @Inject
    @Named("endCaption")
    private MenuItem menuItem;

}
```

and in Guice Module

```
    String[] captions = { "startCaption", "endCaption" };

    for(final String caption : captions)
    {
        bind(MenuItem.class).annotatedWith(Names.named(caption)).toProvider(
        new Provider<MenuItem>()
        {
            public MenuItem get()
            {
                return new MenuItemImpl(caption);
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In my example, the multibinder is used as plug-in mechanism. I don't know the concrete instances at compile time, hence I cannot name them. The consuming code would look like this:     @Inject Set<MenuItem> contributedMenuItems; Also, If the MenuItemImpl is instantiated within the provider manually, dependend beans are not injected.